# Can someone determine what kind of file is this? I got it from a BLOB Field

Tags: file, format, blob, firebird, binary-data

I got this file from a BLOB field through a database query. There are a lot of '%HEX' values which I'm kinda confused what it's for. Is anybody familiar wih this file format? I need to revert it back to a readable form. Any help is much appreciated.

> %00%01%00%00%00%ff%ff%ff%ff%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%0c%02%00%00%00IAnalysisWebClient%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%0c%03%00%00%00IProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%05%01%00%00%00DMatrikon.ProcessGuard.AnalysisWebClient.WebReports.Model.ReportModel%08%00%00%00%0cAnalysisHost%0aReportName%08ConfigId%0bReportTitle%0dFilterModel41%0dPropertyNames%0cPropertyList%15ReportComponentConfig%01%01%00%01%04%03%03%03%080com.matrikon.processguard.earm.model.FilterModel%03%00%00%00%1cSystem.Collections.ArrayList%1cSystem.Collections.Hashtable%1cSystem.Collections.Hashtable%02%00%00%00%06%04%00%00%00%0fMTK-SUPADEMO-V2%06%05%00%00%00%12AlarmCountOverTime%bd%01%00%00%06%06%00%00%00%08TestAMRS%09%07%00%00%00%09%08%00%00%00%09%09%00%00%00%09%0a%00%00%00%05%07%00%00%000com.matrikon.processguard.earm.model.FilterModel%02%00%00%00%0fFieldFilterList%13PlantViewFilterList%03%04%9e%01System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5b%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.MessageCriteria%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d3com.matrikon.processguard.earm.PlantViewFilterGroup%03%00%00%00%03%00%00%00%09%0b%00%00%00%09%0c%00%00%00%04%08%00%00%00%1cSystem.Collections.ArrayList%03%00%00%00%06_items%05_size%08_version%05%00%00%08%08%09%0d%00%00%00%1a%00%00%00%1a%00%00%00%04%09%00%00%00%1cSystem.Collections.Hashtable%07%00%00%00%0aLoadFactor%07Version%08Comparer%10HashCodeProvider%08HashSize%04Keys%06Values%00%00%03%03%00%05%05%0b%08%1cSystem.Collections.IComparer%24System.Collections.IHashCodeProvider%08%ecQ8%3f%9d%00%00%00%0a%0a%2f%00%00%00%09%0e%00%00%00%09%0f%00%00%00%01%0a%00%00%00%09%00%00%00%ecQ8%3f%06%00%00%00%0a%0a%0b%00%00%00%09%10%00%00%00%09%11%00%00%00%04%0b%00%00%00%9e%01System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5b%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.MessageCriteria%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%03%00%00%00%06_items%05_size%08_version%04%00%000com.matrikon.processguard.earm.MessageCriteria%5b%5d%03%00%00%00%08%08%09%12%00%00%00%02%00%00%00%18%00%00%00%05%0c%00%00%003com.matrikon.processguard.earm.PlantViewFilterGroup%01%00%00%00%0dPlantViewRoot%04%24com.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%03%00%00%00%03%00%00%00%09%13%00%00%00%10%0d%00%00%00+%00%00%00%06%14%00%00%00%09Condition%06%15%00%00%00%07EndTime%06%16%00%00%00%0bOutStanding%06%17%00%00%00%08Interval%06%18%00%00%00%07MaxRows%06%19%00%00%00%0dStartTimeType%06%1a%00%00%00%0bEndTimeType%06%1b%00%00%00%0fRelativeEndTime%06%1c%00%00%00%11RelativeStartTime%06%1d%00%00%00%15RelativeStartTimeType%06%1e%00%00%00%13RelativeEndTimeType%06%1f%00%00%00%17RelativeStartAnchorTime%06+%00%00%00%15RelativeEndAnchorTime%06!%00%00%00%09StartTime%06%22%00%00%00%0eTimeZoneOffset%06%23%00%00%00%14ThresholdMarkerStart%06%24%00%00%00%12ThresholdMarkerEnd%06%25%00%00%00%0aThresholds%06%26%00%00%00%0cIncludedRows%06'%00%00%00%09FieldList%06(%00%00%00%12TimeFrameIntervals%06)%00%00%00%0dTimeFrameType%06*%00%00%00%0aGroupLevel%06%2b%00%00%00%0cMaxPieSlices%06%2c%00%00%00%10LastGenerateTime%06-%00%00%00%0cCustomEvents%0d%06%10%0e%00%00%00%11%00%00%00%06.%00%00%00%1eAlarmCountOverTimeColumnHeader%06%2f%00%00%00%08Interval%060%00%00%00%15RelativeEndAnchorTime%061%00%00%00%0bEndTimeType%062%00%00%00%09StartTime%063%00%00%00%0dStartTimeType%064%00%00%00%17RelativeStartAnchorTime%065%00%00%00%11RelativeStartTime%066%00%00%00%09PageIndex%067%00%00%00%07EndTime%068%00%00%00%0fRelativeEndTime%09%2c%00%00%00%06%3a%00%00%00%15RelativeStartTimeType%06%3b%00%00%00%07MaxRows%06%3c%00%00%00%0bOutStanding%06%3d%00%00%00%13RelativeEndTimeType%06%3e%00%00%00%0eTimeZoneOffset%10%0f%00%00%00%11%00%00%00%09%3f%00%00%00%08%08%09%00%00%00%08%0d%00%40W+S%05Q%08%06%40%00%00%00%010%08%0d%00%c0%a4%ec%f8%a1%ce%08%09%40%00%00%00%08%0d%00%40W+S%05Q%08%06A%00%00%00%04*-1d%06B%00%00%00%011%08%0d%00%80%0e%17%c2%a2%ce%08%06C%00%00%00%01*%08%0d%f0%17%25c!%a4%ce%88%09%40%00%00%00%08%08%14%00%00%00%0a%09%40%00%00%00%08%08l%fd%ff%ff%10%10%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%06E%00%00%00%19AlarmCountOverTime_Grid_2%10%11%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%09F%00%00%00%07%12%00%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%04%00%00%00%04.com.matrikon.processguard.earm.MessageCriteria%03%00%00%00%09G%00%00%00%09H%00%00%00%0d%02%05%13%00%00%00%24com.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%01%00%00%00%08Children%03%f7%01System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%03%00%00%00%09I%00%00%00%04%3f%00%00%00%7fSystem.Collections.Generic.List%601%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%03%00%00%00%06_items%05_size%08_version%06%00%00%08%08%09J%00%00%00%05%00%00%00%05%00%00%00%05F%00%00%00MMatrikon.ProcessGuard.AnalysisWebClient.WebReports.View.ReportComponentConfig%04%00%00%00%03Key%0cColumnWidths%0dSortedColumns%0eSortIndicators%01%03%03%03%1cSystem.Collections.ArrayList%7eSystem.Collections.Generic.List%601%5b%5bSystem.Int32%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%a5%02System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5b%5bSystem.Int32%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bInfragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.SortIndicator%2c+Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v6.3%2c+Version%3d6.3.20063.1059%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d7dd5c3163f2cd0cb%5d%5d%02%00%00%00%06K%00%00%00%19AlarmCountOverTime_Grid_2%09L%00%00%00%09M%00%00%00%09N%00%00%00%05G%00%00%00.com.matrikon.processguard.earm.MessageCriteria%03%00%00%00%05Field%09Condition%05Value%01%01%01%03%00%00%00%06O%00%00%00%0aSuppressed%06P%00%00%00%01%3d%06Q%00%00%00%010%01H%00%00%00G%00%00%00%06R%00%00%00%03Tag%06S%00%00%00%02!%3d%06T%00%00%00%02XX%04I%00%00%00%f7%01System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%04%00%00%00%07Version%08Comparer%08HashSize%0dKeyValuePairs%00%03%00%03%08%92%01System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer%601%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%08%fb%01System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%5b%5d%1f%00%00%00%09U%00%00%00%03%00%00%00%09V%00%00%00%11J%00%00%00%08%00%00%00%06W%00%00%00%08Interval%06X%00%00%00%05Count%06Y%00%00%00%0cDistribution%06Z%00%00%00%03SOE%06%5b%00%00%00%0bTop20Alarms%0d%03%01L%00%00%00%08%00%00%00%09%5c%00%00%00%04%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%04M%00%00%00%7eSystem.Collections.Generic.List%601%5b%5bSystem.Int32%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%03%00%00%00%06_items%05_size%08_version%07%00%00%08%08%08%09%5d%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%04N%00%00%00%a5%02System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5b%5bSystem.Int32%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bInfragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.SortIndicator%2c+Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v6.3%2c+Version%3d6.3.20063.1059%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d7dd5c3163f2cd0cb%5d%5d%03%00%00%00%07Version%08Comparer%08HashSize%00%03%00%08%91%01System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer%601%5b%5bSystem.Int32%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%08%00%00%00%00%09%5e%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%04U%00%00%00%92%01System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer%601%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%00%00%00%00%07V%00%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%02%00%00%00%03%f9%01System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%04%a1%ff%ff%ff%f9%01System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%02%00%00%00%03key%05value%01%04%24com.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%03%00%00%00%06%60%00%00%00%0a(No+Plant)%09a%00%00%00%01%9e%ff%ff%ff%a1%ff%ff%ff%06c%00%00%00%0aDemo+Plant%09d%00%00%00%10%5c%00%00%00%04%00%00%00%06e%00%00%00%00%09e%00%00%00%09e%00%00%00%09e%00%00%00%0f%5d%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%08%04%5e%00%00%00%91%01System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer%601%5b%5bSystem.Int32%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%00%00%00%00%01a%00%00%00%13%00%00%00%09f%00%00%00%01d%00%00%00%13%00%00%00%09g%00%00%00%04f%00%00%00%f7%01System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%03%00%00%00%07Version%08Comparer%08HashSize%00%03%00%08%92%01System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer%601%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%08%00%00%00%00%09h%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%01g%00%00%00I%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%09h%00%00%00%03%00%00%00%09i%00%00%00%01h%00%00%00U%00%00%00%07i%00%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%03%f9%01System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%01%96%ff%ff%ff%a1%ff%ff%ff%06k%00%00%00%09Utilities%09l%00%00%00%01l%00%00%00%13%00%00%00%09m%00%00%00%01m%00%00%00I%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%09h%00%00%00%03%00%00%00%09o%00%00%00%07o%00%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%03%f9%01System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%01%90%ff%ff%ff%a1%ff%ff%ff%06q%00%00%00%06Heater%09r%00%00%00%01r%00%00%00%13%00%00%00%09s%00%00%00%04s%00%00%00%f7%01System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%2c%5bcom.matrikon.processguard.earm.Level%2c+ProcessGuard.Core%2c+Version%3d4.3.3.58%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull%5d%5d%03%00%00%00%07Version%08Comparer%08HashSize%00%03%00%08%92%01System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer%601%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%2c+Version%3d2.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db77a5c561934e089%5d%5d%08%00%00%00%00%09h%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%0b

Comment: Finally a good use for the "too localized" close reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but it looks like a binary serialization of a .NET object, which is percent-encoded.

See http://primates.ximian.com/~lluis/dist/binary_serialization_format.htm for a description of the format.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge, i was running out of ideas